# Awaiting recommendation will take how long time?

Tags: journal-workflow

I submitted a paper to some journal. Within less than two months it came for minor revision. Then I submitted the revised manuscript in 10 days. After two and half months the status got changed from awaiting reviewer scores to awaiting recommendation. Now it is almost 3 weeks. Still the status is same. How long I should wait for the final verdict?
Thanking you.

Comment: See here possibly : https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/65111/72855

Comment: I have to say that, in my opinion, academic life before on-line submission status was much, much nicer. You sent it off and didn't worry about it until you got an envelope back in the mail. These things take time.

Comment: “Patience is a virtue” and, unlike the internet, journals review material to control quality and as has been pointed out, the submission systems where you click and get told what is happening is mych faster than post... I sometimes think some people check the status twice a day if not more...

Answer (score 0):

Check if there are any major holidays in the editor's country. If not, three weeks should be enough to make a decision. However, it can be that the editor invited another reviewer to have a look at the paper (possibly after receiving the 2nd round of reviews), which will cause a few weeks delay.

If you don't want to wait longer send a short, friendly email to the editorial office. They should be able to tell you if the paper is still in the pipeline or whether it got stuck somewhere, and maybe when you can expect an answer.

Maybe the editor is just on holidays...

Comment: Now Christmas is near. Between after the recommendation, through which step manuscript will go?

Comment: Editorial decision (accept, revision, reject). However, it can be that more reviews will be needed before a decision is taken. For more information on workflow, see here: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/55665/what-does-the-typical-workflow-of-a-journal-look-like

Comment: Dear Mark, if the status is showing awaiting decision, what is the meaning of this? And how long I should wait for final verdict?

Comment: Dear Mark, now the status is awaiting decision since 2 weeks. Now how long it takes the time? Thank you..

Comment: @thomus Usually it's quick, but dependent on the journal, it may take longer. As written in the canonical answer linked in my previous comment, for some journals the decision is taken by a team rather than a single editor. Many countries still have (school) holidays, therefore some editors may be on holidays, and the decision has to wait until they return. Given the holiday season, I would wait another week before asking. Check with your colleagues how things go with the specific journal in question. Then, if you think you waited long enough, send an email to a contact person at the journal.